# Save video tag tag data to blob without loss of resolution

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

How to convert `<video />` data to canvas image without loss in resolution?

Tried something like this: https://medium.com/@immanubhardwaj/javascript-how-to-capture-image-from-video-ac7dba01a8e7
Created canvas and then retrieved image from there. The problem with this approach is, the image quality is reduced.

Is there any other way to solve this problem.

Comment: There is no reason for the image to lose its quality doing the method in the link. You probably did *something-wrong™*

Comment: No, while converting video tag to image data upon clicking Capture loses image quality

Comment: [Once again,] There is no reason for the image to lose its quality doing the method in the link. You probably did *something-wrong™*. [show us what you did].